# Append a Rectangle to the old Rectangles

Tags: c#, arrays, timer, drawrectangle

Hye there I am new to C# and learning it to my own. My problem is that I want to append a new rectangle to the old rectangles and move them all using a timer my code is:

```
Rectangle[] rec;
int rec_part = 4;
int rec_x = 0;
Color c = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    rec = new Rectangle[rec_part];   
    for (int i = 0; i < rec_part; i++)
    {
        rec_x += 43;
        rec[i] = new Rectangle(rec_x, 100, 40,40);
    }
}
```

it will initialize 4 Rectangles, then:

```
Graphics g;

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    g = e.Graphics;
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    for (int i = 0; i < rec_part; i++)
        g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), rec[i]);
}
```

This will draw 4 Rectangle Controls on the Form, then:

```
int speed = 2;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rec.Length; i++)
    {
        rec[i].X += speed;
        rec_part += 1;  \\Here I want to append a new Rectangle to the existing rectangles 
        \\ the array size is to increment so that that a new rectangle will append 
    }
    Refresh();
}
```

But the problem is that an "index out of range" exception has been thrown within my code but if I use my timer as:

```
int speed = 2;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rec.Length; i++)
    {
        rec[i].X += speed;
        if (rec_part == rec.Length)
            rec_part = 0;
        else
            rec_part += 1;
    }
    Refresh();
}
```

All works fine with this code, but it starts blinking so much so that one can unable to watch it perfectly, and every time it draws new rectangles in number of 4 whereas I want to append a new rectangle!
Sorry for my English. Can somebody help me out sorting thing problem? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I advise you adding the rectangles to a list instead of an array.

I also advice you not to use winforms for drawing rectangles WPF is way faster in drawing lots of stuff it's a bit more complicated but it's faster.

reply if you need any code samples and i'll update my answer

This is my code:

```
          rectangles2[i] = rectangleupdated(rectangles2[i]);
```

Rectangles2 is a list of rectangles, rectangleupdated has as parameters an rectangles then it modifys the rectangles like this:

```
Rectangle rectangleupdated(Rectangle rect){
    return rect.Y--;
}
```

This is my result after collision checking and everything(It's a powdergame)
[image]

Comment: I have been trying with the list also but how I am unable to move my rectangle in timer!

Comment: Please can you give some sample code I am new to do this work!

Comment: Sorry, I'll reply in a few hours I'm at school atm and I seem to have my old code at home.

Comment: Can you please give some more sample code i am new to this work not getting this little One